# Count of non-repeating digits

Tags: algorithm

Given a number, return the count of numbers having non-repeating digits till that number starting from 1.

**Test case 1:**

Sample input

```
7
```

sample output

```
7
```

**Test case 2:**

Sample input

```
3456
```

sample output

```
2562
```

---

I will write the program but I don't know what is problem statement is asking as sample input test cases are confusing me.

Comment: @rsp The OP did not understand the question in order to write a code.

Comment: Seems like a good question for whoever wrote this assignment, rather than here...

Comment: In the future, please format your questions a bit better and share anything you tried. The assignment is asking, from `1` to `n`, how many numbers do not repeat a digit. For example, `1111` repeats the digit `1`, 4 times. `1122` repeats 2 different digits. `1234` repeats *no* digits. If you have trouble writing the code, please ask here, but this type of question is best asked in a chat room.

Comment: ok@Aaron3468.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question *is* ambiguous, since there's two reasonable ways of interpreting "repeated digit".

- First, a number has a "repeated digit" if it has the same digit twice or more in succession. For example 12334 has a repeated digit (3).
- Second, a number has a repeated digit if the same digit appears twice. So 1231 would not have a repeated digit in the first sense, but would in the this sense (1 repeats).

We can find which meaning is correct by checking the test cases they give.

```
def nonrep1(n):
    return sum(all(c != d for c, d in zip(str(i), str(i)[1:])) for i in xrange(1, n+1))

def nonrep2(n):
    return sum(all(str(i).count(d) < 2 for d in '0123456789') for i in xrange(1, n+1))

assert nonrep1(7) == 7
assert nonrep1(3456) == 2562

assert nonrep2(7) == 7
assert nonrep2(3456) == 2562
```

The final assertion fails, so the first meaning of "non repeated" is the one intended by the problem-setter.

I have written slightly silly terse versions of the programs so you can still write your own code now that you understand what the problem is asking.

Comment: sir I unable to understand the return statement. It will be of great help if you will elaborate a bit more

Comment: only return statement

Answer (score 1):

The question is that given a number N. Find how many numbers are there from 1 to N which do-not have repeating digits.

In the first case there are 7 numbers from 1 to 7 which don't have repeating digits.

In the second case there are 2562 numbers from 1 to 3456 which don't have repeating digits.