# Given a number, return the count of numbers having non-repeating digits till that number starting from 1?

Tags: java, algorithm

Let's assume it means two consecutive digits can not be the same.
If it means that all digits are unique the logic is very similar as well.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class solution {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int no = scan.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<=no;i++)
        {
          String a = Integer.toString(i);
          char[] b =a.toCharArray();

          Arrays.sort(b);
          String x = new String(b);
      //    System.out.println("Sorted array:"+x);
          int flag = 0;
          if(a.length()>1)
        {
          for(int j=1;j<a.length();j++)
          {
            //System.out.println(b[j-1]+"=="+b[j]);
            if( (b[j-1]==b[j]))
            {
              flag =1;
            //  System.out.println("Has Repeated Numbers!");
              break;
            }
          }
        }
          if(flag == 0)
          {
            count++;
          //  System.out.println("count:"+count+" --> "+"No:"+a);
          }
        }
        System.out.println("Final Count:"+count);
   }
}
```

**INPUT 1:** 3456

**OUTPUT 1:** 2562

**INPUT 2:** 22

**OUTPUT 2:** 20

**INPUT 3:** 7

**OUTPUT 3:** 7

**INPUT 4:** 100

**OUTPUT 4:** 90

**INPUT 5:** 37

**OUTPUT 5:** 34

My code satisfies input test cases from 2 to 5 but not for input 1.
I understand that every digit should be unique in a number. Can anyone say where I have done my mistake in my logic from the code for input1?

Comment: This is still something that you could /should learn to debug yourself, but this newbie question is so much better to most others I saw today that you get my vote.

Comment: the `String a` and the `char[]` array is local to the for loop you might want to rethink it considering that String are immutable you can use StringBuilder instead

Comment: So a number like 707 shouldn't be counted either?  At this point, your code would count 707, right?

Comment: To my knowledge it should not be counted as there are 7(repeated twice) in the given number 707.@NickZiebert

Comment: You write "Let's assume it means two consecutive digits can not be the same". But your answer and comments here assume it means no two digits can be the same. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200669/count-of-non-repeating-digits/43209711#43209711 which has the same test cases, and I show the no-two-consecutive-digits interpretation is indeed correct.

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks for pointing out my wrong interpretation. Now my program works like charm. I should be more careful understanding the problem statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What  gone **wrong** in my logic is  **here I assumed  no two digits can be the same**, but the looking keenly on the problem statement it **says no two consecutive digits can not be the same**.

Here is the working code for the above input test cases. Thanks to Paul Hankin for pointing out.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class solution {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int no = scan.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<=no;i++)
        {
          String a = Integer.toString(i);
          char[] b =a.toCharArray();
          int flag = 0;
          if(a.length()>1)
        {
          for(int j=1;j<a.length();j++)
          {
            //System.out.println(b[j-1]+"=="+b[j]);
            if( (b[j-1]==b[j]))
            {
              flag =1;
            //  System.out.println("Has Repeated Numbers!");
              break;
            }
          }
        }
          if(flag == 0)
          {
            count++;
            //System.out.println("count:"+count+" --> "+"No:"+a);
          }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean *no two consecutive digits can be the same* (without the “not” between “can” and “be”)

Answer (score 2):

Use regex!

```
int count = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
    .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
    .filter(s -> s.matches("(?!.*?(.)\\1).*"))
    .count();
```